# printing logs to /var/log/tomcat6/catalina.out

Tags: java, logging, tomcat, applet

I have a content-resolver.war file which I extracted to this folder /var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/.

This is a java application project I want to debug and print logs into /var/log/tomcat6/catalina.out how can I do that. I tried configuring the log4j.properties file but nothing gets printed. 
(/var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/content-resolver.backup/WEB-INF/log4j.properties)

```
### stdout appender ###
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=[%C] %p %d{HH:mm:ss.SSS}: %m%n
```

log4j.appender.dailyRollingFileAppender=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
  log4j.appender.dailyRollingFileAppender.File=/opt/Fabrix.TV/logs/gui.log

Comment: How are you writing that log content? Can you show a sample statement writing to logs as well as the configuration you referred to?

Comment: I can't put it up here, it won't format it to code